# syslog-ng configure on RHEL 7 fails with OpenSSL version 0.9.8 dependency

Tags: rhel, openssl, configure, syslog-ng

Building latest syslog-ng (3.17.2, rather than the packaged version in EPEL, which is 3.5.6, built 30-Dec-2015) from https://github.com/balabit/syslog-ng/releases

Amidst `./configure --prefix=/app/syslog-ng`, it gives error:

`configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL libraries with version >= 0.9.8 it is a hard dependency from syslog-ng 3.7 onwards`

---

```
# yum install openssl
Loaded plugins: package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager 

  .......

Package 1:openssl-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version

# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
# rpm -qa|grep -i openssl
pyOpenSSL-0.13.1-3.el7.x86_64
openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.i686
openssl-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64
openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64
# cat /etc/system-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
#
```

How do I resolve this config error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configure` is looking for the relevant openssl development files and cannot find them.  On your RHEL 7 system, easiest way to achieve this is to `yum install openssl-devel` and then retry.